# How to use regex in gitlab-ci if rules?

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would be very happy if someone could help me with the following issue.
I would like to run specific scripts only for tags starting with a given tag name.

The following rule works well for the tag 'wind-index' but what I need is a regex as I would like it to work also for tags such as 'wind-index_0.1'

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == "wind-index"
      when: always
```

I was expecting this to work but without success....

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == \^wind-index\
      when: always
```

I've tried all possible combinations with simple quotes, double quotes or `\^wind-index.*\`, none are working.

Any suggestion, help is more than welcome :-)

Comment: `- if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^wind-index/`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258479/3832970).

Comment: This means if $CI_COMMIT_TAG starts with `wind-index` do something.

Comment: Thanks both for your excellent and rapid help! I was not aware of the meaning of =~.
This solved my issue :-) Thanks again !

Both answers were right and helpful but I could only accept one as answer :-( So, I took the quickest one as arbitrary criteria.

Comment: Why don't you select a more helpful answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^wind-index/
```

Comment: Thanks Cubix48 for your quick replay. But I don't understand the concept as this would mean:
"if the variable CI_COMMIT_TAG does not match the regex ^wind_index, then run the script " ??

Comment: As @Wiktor Stribiżew explained in his answer, `=~` is not an inequality operator but a regex matching operator.

Answer (score 8):

You need

- `/` as regex delimiters
- `==` is equality comparison operator, you need a regex matching operator, `=~`.

You can use

```
 rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^wind-index/
      when: always
```